# Need to pull multiple values from python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary with tuple keys, like so:

```
(1111, 3454): 34.55555
(1123, 4665): 67.12
(1111, 9797): 5.09
```

I need to do a list comprehension that grabs the values for all entries with a matching first element.
Problem is, I ALSO need that second value of the tuple...

```
interimlist = [v for k,v in mydict.items() if k[0]==item[0]]
```

Is what I've got right now for pulling the values if the first element of the tuple is correct (item is an iterator variable). I'd like the output to be a list of tuples of (value, second tuple number), so with the example points, would be the following output if item[0] is 1111:

```
[(34.55555, 3454), (5.09, 9797)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict is not stored with a good with a good structure here.  All the keys/vals must be iterated in order to do one lookup, so it is O(n) retrieval.

You should do a once-off re-keying of the data, adding another level of nesting in the dict:

```
>>> d
{(1111, 3454): 34.55555, (1123, 4665): 67.12, (1111, 9797): 5.09}
>>> d_new = {}
>>> for (k1, k2), v in d.items():
...     if k1 not in d_new:
...         d_new[k1] = {}
...     d_new[k1][k2] = v
```

And now, O(1) lookups are restored:

```
>>> d_new[1111]
{3454: 34.55555, 9797: 5.09}
>>> [item[::-1] for item in d_new[1111].items()]
[(34.55555, 3454), (5.09, 9797)]
```

Comment: Little did you know my actual dictionary is 1.8 million items (don't ask it's necessary for the rest of my work) and that restoration of O(1) was CRITICAL for keeping my time down :)